# Unable to open PerfmonCfg file with counters added to it in Qt

Tags: qt

I created a PerfmonCfg file with some counters. When I open a *.PerfmonCfg file from Qt using QProcess::startDetached or QDesktopServices::openUrl, it is opening a performance counter with no counters added into it. But when I open a *.PerfmonCfg directly(through explorer), it opens with the counters(which are added while creating the *.PerfmonCfg file).

Comment: Your call to ```QDesktopServices::openUrl(QUrl("file:///path/to/file.ext", QUrl::TolerantMode))``` should have the same effect as the explorer. Did this call still just open the default Perfmon?

Comment: @SebastianLange: Yes. Still open a default perfmon